# PySide and Qt Property Framework

Tags: qt, properties, frameworks, pyside

Is it possible to use the [Qt Property Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq18-propertybrowser.html) with [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/)? If not, do you have hints on how to achieve similar behaviour using [Qt MVC Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/model-view-programming.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this qestion is a bit old... 
**Yes**, you can use it quite well. Have a look [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_UsingQtProperties) as example. AFAIK there are efforts to use Python @properties as Qt properties as well.

Comment: Link is not valid anymore.